# CSS: Images not scaling correctly

Tags: html, css, image

I'm new to CSS and I am trying to scaled 2 pictures, which are in the same class, to the same perecentage: height: x% and width: y%, however they are not coming out the same size. If it matters, I did not set the size in my HTML file either. Here is what I got:

```
.BlogBoxes { 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 20px 1000px 20px 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 50px 30px; 
    background-color: #FFCEB7;
}

.BlogBoxes img {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    height: 80%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Here is a screenshot, if it helps
[image: screenshot]

Comment: They share the same width %% already. Your browser tries not to stretch the images this only scales them to either width or height. Your best bet is to use images that share the same dimensions already.

Comment: @Phil M if I tried setting the width and height in HTML, as well as in CSS, would that do anything or do I really just have to pick new pics?

Comment: You can specify them as hardcoded values like 'width: 100px'. But remember these images are most likely stretching then.

Comment: The HTML is important here. I assume the image is a child of a `p` or `div` element that has no defined height. And `80%` of undefined is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the width you are after to a parent element of the image, and then set the image to have a max-width of 100%.

So in your case you want the image to take up 25% of '.BlogBoxes', so we'll create a new div inside that '.img-container', and then place the img inside of that.

```
.BlogBoxes div.img-container {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  /*height: 80%; // forget height this is not necessary */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.BlogBoxes div.img-container img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: _"forget height this is not necessary"_ - Take a look at the screenshot. The problem is exclusively about height!

Comment: Yes but that is not doing anything. Remove the height style from your '.BlogBoxes' class as well.

Comment: "Yes but that is not doing anything" - **That's the problem!**

Comment: That's not how responsive images work. Applying height values to your elements wont work either unless you've defined all the elements in your html hierarchy. The 'height: 30%;' on .BlogBoxes is doing nothing. Let the content define the height. At the moment you just have to fix the issue you have which is that you've set your image to be 25% of the width of the container and it doesn't work for your second image because it is taller at that width than the content. Implement the solution i added and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Here you can see a working example. I have made some other updates to the markup. I did not notice this originally in your css 'margin: 20px 1000px 20px 10px;'

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/bLx3vtu4/embedded/result/